# CSS issue with overflow hidden

Tags: css

How to disable to scroll right.

Do i need to put overflow-hidden somewhere? Or is it something else?

Wrapper width is 1100px.

Comment: On my end it's enabled only if you resize the browser window, otherwise it's disabled. What is the problem?

Comment: Seems fine to me also, unless you zoom into the page. Try setting your browser view to 100% and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: I see not scrollbar on your screenshot nor the live site. What do you mean ? Please try to narrow down your problem and if possible making a  jsFiddle out of it

Comment: It is disabled but your page isn't in the middle its push to the left.

Comment: I can scroll sideways on firefox, chrome and from mobile devices, but there is noting there to see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set the width of **#wrapper** to **1100px** keep it same as of **#bildspel** which is **947px** .

Comment: I tried to change the wrapper to 1100px but nothing happens.

Comment: It is currently 1100px , which is larger than the width of above slider as well , reduce it to 900px or atleast make it equal to the width of your slider.